# Bootstrap navbar - fixed on mobile on horizontal website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a horizontal website. I've tried setting the top menu (navbar) to `position:fixed` or giving it the `navbar-fixed-top` class, experimenting with %, but on mobile (iPhone 5 at least) I end up with the navbar either taking the width of the entire page (so the menu button is on the very right and only visible when I scroll to the last page), either it's only visible on the first page and scrolls away when I scroll to the right.

Here's the simplified code:

HTML:

```
<body>
   <nav class="navbar">
   here goes the typical Boostrap navbar construction
   </nav>
   <div class="big-wrap">
      <section id="one">
      </section>
      <section id="two">
      </section>
      <section id="three">
      </section>
      <section id="four">
      </section>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 html {position: relative;}
 html, body {height: 100%}
 .big-wrap {position: absolute;width: 400%}
 section {float:left;width:25%;}
```

How can I make the navbar appear as full width and sticking in the same place when scrolling to other sections, both on desktop and mobile (on desktop it's ok for now)?

Comment: You can't use `navbar-fixed-top` for nav. you've to play with `position` property.

Comment: @Ravimallya I'm trying that too, but no success. I hope I can avoid javascript.

Comment: share us what you've tried so far in a [bootply](http://bootply.com) snippet and update the question accordingly.

Comment: do u have code in jsfiddle? because you code looks like in complete